# convert Calendar date to Julian Date in Unix

Tags: shell, ubuntu, unix

I have one requirement. in one of the source file I'm getting calendar date as input and while processing the file it has to convert Julian Date format. I just need a Script.

ex:Date: 10-Nov-2020
Julian Date: 2020314

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is

```
date -d 10-Nov-2020 +%Y%j
```

but it seems to count from 1, not 0, so it returns `2020315`.

Perl's [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) can be used to get the expected value:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lwe '$t = localtime->strptime(shift, "%d-%b-%Y"); print $t->year, $t->yday' -- 10-Nov-2020
```

You might need `sprintf "%03d", $t->yday` instead of just `$t->yday` if you want 2020000 instead of 20200 for the first day.